# Configure SVN repo url in Visual Studio Code

Tags: svn, repository

Using Visual Studio Code, how do you set the URL for an SVN repository?  I installed Chris Johnston's SVN extension and the Collabnet SVN client executable.  Is there no config item in settings.json where the repo url can be provided...?

Answer (score 2):

I installed the Johnston SVN to my Visual Studio Code. In the extension, I clicked on the gear icon which shows me the UI setting changes. I enter the project folder path from my PC. I clicked close editor and restart my Visual Studio. When VS is loaded, you will see the "S" on the left pane. Click on it and you will see the Repository to add your SVN URL. Hope this helps someone. I know this extension does not have the greatest documentation.

Answer (score 2):

here are the steps to solve

- Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`
- Type and chose SVN: Checkout. Press `Enter`
- Input existing URL of your repository e.g. `file:///C:/Users/user1/Repo/my_scripts`. Press `Enter`
- Input parent directory for your Work copy e.g. `C:\Users\user1\Documents`. Press `Enter`
- Input name of directory your Work copy e.g. `"my_scripts"`. Press `Enter`

Enjoy!